# Which type of join to use?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called PROJECT_CATEGORY and it contains two fields

cat_id and cat_title

I am storing the cat_id in another table called PROJECTS so:

```
project_category.cat_id = projects.cat_id
```

What is the best way using MySQL to run a query to show the `cat_title`. In other words I want to display the name not the ID number of the table. Would this work:

```
SELECT * FROM projects INNER JOIN projects ON project_category.cat_id = projects.cat_id
```

Then call it:

```
'.$row['cat_title'].'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If *every* project has a valid cat_id and cat_id is unique, than INNER JOIN is fine.

If any project has a NULL cat_id, you want a LEFT JOIN.

If cat_id is not a unique field (primary key), you may want to use a subquery to limit yourself to one result per project.

Comment: Yes...every project WILL have some type of category it belongs too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  projects.cat_id cat_id
FROM
  projects INNER JOIN
  project_category ON project_category.cat_id = projects.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cat_title 
FROM projects 
    INNER JOIN project_category ON project_category.cat_id = projects.cat_id
```

That should work.

Comment: And to display the cat_title, I can use:

'.$row['cat_title'].'

I tried that and get a blank output, with no errors

Comment: Run the query in a query analyser like phpMyAdmin and see if you get any results. If not, you might not have any data for some reason, otherwise you're probably reading the field in php incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use SELECT *, instead choose the specific fields you need. Also, if you use multiple tables in a query, alias them properly so you can pull out values as needed and not run into ambiguity problems.

Anyways, you could try something like:

```
SELECT       
 project_category.cat_title 
 ,projects.*  
FROM   
 projects   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN     
   project_category
    ON project_category.cat_id = projects.cat_id
```

Comment: That seemed to get my data to pull, but not the category. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that each project has a project_category associated with it? Maybe you could post your table schemas (desc project, desc project_category are the commands I think for MySQL) and a sample row of data.

Comment: The table PROJECT_CATEGORY as TWO fields (cat_id,cat_title), an example is:

1,E-Commerce

On my PROJECTS table I have cat_id for there is a relationship there, so I am trying to display the CAT_TITLE instead of the CAT_ID

Comment: If you run the query through phpMyAdmin or MySQL Query, are you seeing the full results with the category? If so, it could be a problem with the way you're trying to reference the field in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your join looks fine.  FWIW, I'd use the `USING` clause in this case.  It works the same, but it's a bit more clear and concise:

```
SELECT * FROM projects INNER JOIN project_category USING (cat_id);
```

If you're having trouble finding the column in your `$row` associative array, I'd check the spelling of your column definition, including capitalization.  If you declared your table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `Project_Category` (
  `Cat_ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `Cat_Title` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Then the result set may use that literal spelling and capitalization in the array keys.  PHP array keys are case-sensitive.

```
print $row['Cat_Title'];
```

You should probably dump the `$row` array to see what it thinks its keys are:

```
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT CAT_TITLE
FROM projects
NATURAL JOIN project_category
```

If the colunms are the same type and not null there is no need to put the fields in the join and it will work fine.